# Check for value discrepancies in recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to check the values of a field in a recordset to see if they are all the same. The field is a string. However, there is no correct value the fields should have, they should simply all be equal to each other.

The idea is that when I call a function if all the fields (Company Name) in the recordset are not equal the function will exit.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you want to compare with what? Please add some sample data to your question, and explain what you are looking for (a query? I can't tell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use a simple count recordset based on company name
>
> Something like this should work - modified for tablename and field name
>
> You want to count number of DISTINCT companynames in your table (or
> query)
>
> If they're all the same - then NumRecs returns 1 unique value

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumRecs FROM " & _
"(SELECT DISTINCT Table1.CompanyName" & _
"FROM Table1) AS t1;"

Set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(strSQL)
if rs!NumRecs = 1 then
 ' all good
else
  ' exit function
endif
```